# My animated Rubics Cube does not react with rigid body simulation. (Blend file attached)

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to create a self-solving Rubics Cube that reacts with ground, via CGI.  Just like this video on youtube: https://youtu.be/2PGjTt4xkWM

But the problem is the animation does not seem to react with the ground. The animation appears like it is just a falling cube. So my question is, How can I make my animated Rubics cube interact with the ground with in the rigid body simulation ?

And in case you need my blend file to answer my question, then here is the blend file: [image]

Comment: The ground must also be a passive rigid body. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, the ground is passive as in the blend file.

Comment: is it even possible to mix animation with physics?

Comment: AFAIK no. You can either have physics or you can animate your own. But you can change this behaviour for every frame - if you want